# Padding in QScrollArea

Tags: user-interface, qt4

I'm a bit new to Qt4's way of laying things out and I've ran across a problem when designing the GUI for a simple image editor.

I want to have the QScrollArea contain the component for image editing. However, I want the component itself to be big enough that one can scroll the entire image completely off view (but only exactly off view; no more) in any direction. Here's a (rough) diagram of what I'm thinking:

[image: Illustration of the said widget.]

(Apparently, you can't scroll horizontally in this diagram...)

So far I haven't really figured out a way to do this. I tried messing with the widget's sizeHint and other things (like using CSS) and none of them seem to work. What should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [QScrollArea::widgetResizable](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qscrollarea.html#widgetResizable-prop) == true property scroll area will try to resize your widget.
Set this property to false.
Or you can adjust your canvas widget size by

```
canvasWidget->setFixedSize(...);
               ||
canvasWidget->setMinimumSize(...);
```

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I needed, but it did somehow end up leading me in the right direction. Although I knew about setFixedSize, this time through using it, I managed to get it to do what I wanted. I changed the Document widget (the big one containing the canvas) to just be a scroll area that spawns a simple QWidget, then used the resizeEvent to resize the QWidget to the desired size. It was much simpler than I thought. I'll give you the answer anyways.